# In git, how does one roll back specific commits in a branch but not roll them back in the parent branch even after merging?

Tags: git, git-flow

Hopefully this will be an easy question. I'm relatively new to git, and there are some things I still don't...git.

Hypothetical situation:

Suppose the develop branch contains two commits, c1 and c2.

A release branch is created after c2, so the release branch also contains c1 and c2.

Then it's decided that c1 needs to be deferred to a later release.

What's the recommended way to remove c1 from the release branch without also then removing c1 from the develop branch when the release branch is merged back into develop?

Comment: Yes, the answer helps... but I wanted to wait to see if anyone had something more elegant.

The three answers I've gotten are:

1) The one below.
2) Re-create the release branch from prior to c1 and then cherry-pick c2 into it.
3) Just revert c1 in the release branch and then let it die (don't merge back to develop).

In my particular case, I'm leaning toward 3.

Comment: yeah. there should be something better. lets wait.

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be a shorter solution. The only other approach I can think of is rebasing the release branch on the commit prior to C1 and then doing cherry-picking surgery.

Comment: rebase your develop branch so c2 comes first, then branch the release off that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if its recommended way or not, but it would solve your problem:

1. Revert commit c1 from release branch. (`git revert <c1-commit-id>`)
2. When merging the release branch to develop, revert the revert commit generated in step1. (`git revert <c1-revert-commit-id>)`

Git revert command:- `git revert <commit-id>`

Comment: Upvote.  Solves the problem but kind of long thing to do this way

Comment: yeah, i know. I believe there would be better solution.